# When I change the variable of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT from the value of 'Development', the Swagger page doesn't work

Tags: swagger, openapi, azure-appservice, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, .net-6.0

I have a Web API based on dot net 6.
This Web API runs on Azure App Service. Azure App Service runs on Linux.

I'm using Open API (Swagger) for test and documentation.
I created 2 appsettings files. (Development and Stage.)

I'm adding ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable to the configuration of Azure App Service like below. Functions work for two variables of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT (Development and Stage).

[image]

when I set the 'Stage' value to ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT, the Swagger page is not working. It gives a 404 Not Found Error. But It works for Development.

Here is my startup code to swagger configuration;

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin", builder => { builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader(); }));
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "AllStore.Api", Version = "v1" });

        var securitySchema = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
            Name = "Authorization",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
            Scheme = "bearer",
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "Bearer"
            }
        };

        c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", securitySchema);

        var securityRequirement = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            { securitySchema, new[] { "Bearer" } }
        };

        c.AddSecurityRequirement(securityRequirement);

    });
}
```

I really don't understand what is the problem? can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the Configure method in the startup.cs like below

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "AllStore.Api v1"));

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });       
}
```

instead of

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "AllStore.Api v1"));
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });       
}
```